# How to integrate Hadoop with SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, hadoop, integration, bigdata, collaboration

As I have requirement of to store large amount of data with faster processing and higher scalability, So I choosen hadoop for this but I requires data collaboration also, I know the  sharepoint is best candidate for it.

Please let me know how to integrate sharepoint with hadoop.
I know the SSIS which is used to SQL server integration with Hadoop but I need realtime examples so I am  able to find out the exact solution for it.

Comment: You need to be more clear about your requirements. Which way do you want to move data? Do you wnat the results of the Map/Reduce jobs on a Hadoop cluster to be published on the SharePoint as soon as they are available? Do you want users to submit some on-demand queries to the Hadoop data via SharePoint?

Comment: All your users should be able to access the server hadoop is one, and all data collaboration should be done there.

Answer (score 0):

Setup HDFS NFS Gateway and copy Sharepoint files. You could also use basic script to PUT the files to HDFS. It would require to use an edge node that has access to SharePoint repository and HDFS client.

HDFS NFS Gateway: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html

HDFS PUT: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put

If you already use HDP and it is installed with Ambari, HDFS NFS Gateway is just another service to add via Ambari.